# Split string (birthday) to get day, month, year

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my database, date is stored as dd/mm/yyyy. When I retrieve it I want to split the date in string day, string month and string year respectively. How should I go about doing it? "/" will be the delimiter is that right?

Comment: Is your database field of type datetime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you get birthDate from database as string, you can use split function to split that string into array like:

```
   string birthDate = "2015/02/01";
   var split = birthDate.Split('/');
```

If you get birthDate from database as datetime, you can extract date parts from it like:

```
    DateTime birthDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

    var year = birthDate.Year;
    var month = birthDate.Month;
    var day = birthDate.Day;
```

Comment: to use the first method you can get year by split[0], get month by split[1] and get day by split[2].

Answer (score 9):

You need can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with format "dd/MM/yyyy": (Where `myString` is the birthday from the database.)

```
string myString = "01/02/2015"; // From Database
DateTime birthday = DateTime.ParseExact(myString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int year = birthday.Year;
int month = birthday.Month;
int day = birthday.Day;
```

You can then use the [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object to get the year, month, day, etc.

Using `string.Split` is an option too, but storing as a `DateTime` allows you to use many handy methods/properties it contains, but you can do it using string.Split as so:

```
string[] birthday = myString.Split('/');
int year, month, day;

int.TryParse(birthday[0], out day);
int.TryParse(birthday[1], out month);
int.TryParse(birthday[2], out year);
```